# unpack all outer-most keys in json object as columns

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a postgres DB called `sales` with a json-object, `data` containing around 100 outer-keys, lets name them `k1,k2,k3..,k100`.

I want to write a query

```
select * from sales some_function(data)
```

which simply returns something like

```
k1    |  k2 | .. | k100
--------------------
"foo" | "bar" | .. | 2
"fizz"| "buzz"| .. | 10
```

ie. just unpacks the keys as columsn and their values as row.
Note, `k1,k2..k100` is not their real name thus I can't do a

`data->> key` loop

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. One restriction of the SQL language is, that all columns (and their data types) must be known to the database when *parsing* the statement - so **before** it is actually run.

You will have to write each one separately:

```
select data ->> 'k1' as k1, data ->> 'k2' as k2, ...
from sales
```

One way to make this easier, is to generate a view dynamically by extracting all JSON keys from the column, then using dynamic SQL to create the view. You will however need to re-create that view each time the number of keys change.

Something along the lines (not tested!)

```
do
$$
declare
  l_columns text;
  l_sql text;
begin
  select string_agg(distinct format('data ->> %L as %I', t.key, t.key), ', ')
    into l_columns
  from sales s
    cross join jsonb_each(s.data) as t(key, value);

  -- l_columns now contains something like: 
  -- data ->> 'k1' as k1, data ->> 'k2' as k2

  -- now create a view from that
  l_sql := 'create view sales_keys as select '||l_columns||' from sales';
  execute l_sql;
end;
$$
;
```

You probably want to add e.g. the primary key column(s) to the view, so that you can match the JSON values back to the original row(s).

Comment: I actually just found the `json_each` function at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html. It seems to do the job (just row-wise).

Comment: @CutePoison: yes, that's the one I used to extract the keys to generate the dynamic SQL. Btw: you shouldn't read the manual for discontinued Postgres versions. Read the manual for the version you are actually using

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that. I will re-run this script everyday, so it wont be a problem to re-create the view when they keys are changed I assume?

Comment: I don't think it will be a problem. Getting the distinct keys from a large table can be quite time-consuming though, you might want to schedule that creation to off-hours

Comment: Will do. Just to be sure - this does not modify the original `sales` DB,right?

Comment: No, it does not